# Shorten my asynchronous DB queries, using async.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I am using

- Node.js
- Express.js
- node-mysql.js
- async.js

I am making multiple asynchronous queries to my DB, but every query relies on the previous one's results, so I decided to use the `waterfall` method.

Right now, my code looks like this (I simplified it with only 2 queries, but there are more):

```
async.waterfall([
    function(cb){
        db.query(insertQuery,values,cb);
    },
    function(results,_,cb){
       var lastInsertId = results.insertId;
       db.query(anotherInsertQuery,otherValues.concat(lastInsertId),cb);
    }
],callback);
```

But I found my code a bit messy, especially the `function(cb) { ... }` wraps.

Is there a way to get rid of those annoying `function(cb){...}` ?

Comment: @Jamal : Thanks for the edit. I wanted to tag my post with `node-mysql.js`, since it's related with that, but I couldn't create it (not enough reputation). Do you think you could do that ?

Comment: At the moment I don't think we need a node-mysql.js tag here

Comment: Welcome to Code Review btw, I don't find your question very clear. Are you asking if your implementation is good, or asking for alternative implementations?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg : Ok I understand. I first hesitated, because I thought it was too specific, but then found out that `async.js` existed, with only one question so...

But anyway, thanks for the welcome ! Sorry about that, I would like to know what's the cleanest way to do what I'm trying to do using the `async.js` module. What methods (`apply`, `waterfall`...) or structure should I use ?

Is that more clear ? Do you think I should edit my question ?

Comment: What exactly is the question @WaldoJeffers? Short and simple, because this is a pretty unclear question.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question and focusing more on "How could this code be improved?" and less on "How would you do it?". It sounds a bit like you want others to come up with a completely new solution from scratch for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks ! I radically shortened it. I still think it made much sense before, if you actually encounter the problem and try to find a solution, but I'll follow your suggestions.

Comment: Well, your comment made me look at the original, which helped me understand the question better, perhaps something to bring up on Meta

Answer (score 1):

I think not.

Whereas you find the `function(cb) { ... }` wraps a bit messy, I think that this is the most elegant way to show readers that this is a separate functions, and that stuff is about to get asynchronous.. Again, compared to other approaches, this is quite clean.

Also, (I know this is just a small example), consider not using the `lastInsertId` variable. You could simply go for

```
async.waterfall([
    function(cb){
        db.query(insertQuery,values,cb);
    },
    function(results,_,cb){
       db.query(anotherInsertQuery,otherValues.concat(results.insertId),cb);
    }
],callback);
```

Comment: Thanks @konijn. I'll wait a bit to see if someone comes with another answer, and will accept yours otherwise.